# Does a ReFS drive on a Windows Storage Pool survive a Windows reinstall?

Tags: windows-8, refs

Or if my SSD that contains my Windows boot and system fails, then I lose the ReFS drive as well?

Comment: I don't know but I would keep [avoiding ReFS / storage spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReFS#Stability_and_known_issues) (or at least storage spaces [pools]) for a few more years. MS is really trying to push it with Windows 8 and make up for earlier lack of success. NTFS is much more mature at this point.

Comment: Also from http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/nas/nas-features/31836-data-recovery-tales-when-windows-storage-spaces-go-bad: "The complexity of Storage Spaces is why we think that development of data recovery algorithms for failed Storage Spaces will be very difficult. ... So if you plan to use Storage Spaces along with thin provisioning to store important data in the near future, we strongly recommend you back up your data. For the foreseeable future, the availability of Storage Spaces recovery software will be iffy." (although that article is slightly old)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll need to look for more backup solutions just in case.